# MediaPlayer - NuPlayerRenderer: possible video time jump of x ms

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, live-wallpaper

I get some lines like the following:

```
10-15 21:34:30.318 6996-20354/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: possible video time jump of 546ms (266286180 : 260922630) or uninitialized media clock, retrying in 10ms
10-15 21:34:30.328 6996-20354/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: possible video time jump of 536ms (266286180 : 260922630) or uninitialized media clock, retrying in 10ms
10-15 21:34:30.338 6996-20354/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: possible video time jump of 526ms (266286180 : 260922630) or uninitialized media clock, retrying in 10ms
10-15 21:34:30.348 6996-20354/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: possible video time jump of 516ms (266286180 : 260922630) or uninitialized media clock, retrying in 10ms
10-15 21:34:30.358 6996-20354/? I/NuPlayerRenderer: possible video time jump of 506ms (266286180 : 260922630) or uninitialized media clock, retrying in 10ms
```

When I use the Media Player to use as Live Wallpaper using WallpaperService.Engine.

```
@Override
public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
    Log.i("VideoWallpaperEngine", "onVisibilityChanged");
    try {
        if(visible)
            mediaPlayer.start();
        else
            mediaPlayer.pause();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While these lines are printed, the video is paused because (I think) he tries to synchronize the video and the audio!?
I am only interested in the video stream and not the audio so does someone have an idea how to skip this check and to simply continue playing the video? Is there a library to play a video (mp4) without this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried testing with a non-audio video file? Does same "time jump" issue still happen?

Comment: Another filetype you mean? Not mp4? Not tried yet... I cannot use GIT because its quality limits...

Comment: Regarding _"the video is paused because (I think) he tries to synchronize the video and the audio!"_ ... Use a different test MP4 that is video only (no audio track) to check if your suspicion is true. Could also just be a corrupt video file being used...

Comment: Awesome, It even shrinked my mp4 from 23MB to 14MB. I will try if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: (by @VC.One)

Use an mp4 without audio line. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwT1FTRjRNQ to remove the audio line from a video using VLC player.

(of course, only if you don't need the audio part of your video)